# [RAILS]: Google Map autocomplete not recording input

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, autocomplete

I developp a rails app with an autocomplete address using google maps API, for my rooms.
The problem is when I try to type inside my product input adress form.. sometimes I have adress suggestion.. sometimes not! And when I have the suggestion, after clicking on it; it does not record my click in the box.
In my rails console I checked if I have the lattitude and longitude for my product: but nothing is recorded.
On my Google developper console, I have a Google API activated, with the same id:
- Google Maps Javascript API key: active; not recording activity
- Google Places for web API Key: active ; recording activity 
I use figaro to hide my keys.
After hours of testing I don't manage to make it work and it makes me crazy..
For info I use an other autocomplete for the same project in my home page. And it works perfectly!

For info: 
I have the following error in my js console for my view:
You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API
And I have no error in my js console for my home page (they use the same API)

Thks for help, here is my code:

My script is in my layout:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY'] %>&libraries=places"></script>

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

My view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= render 'room_menu' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading">
        Location of the bottle
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container">
          <%= form_for @room do |f| %>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Address of the bottle</label>
                <%= f.text_field :address, placeholder: "Where is the bootle?", class: "form-control", required: true, id: "autoaddress" %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
              <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-form" %>
            </div>

          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#autoaddress").geocomplete();
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error `You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API` is because you have not setup `billing information` for your account.

You'll have to enable billing account for your project. For doing that, you can refer [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing)

Comment: Are you sure? Untill now I ve never update my Google account  for an account to pay in test mode app...

Comment: There are 2 kinds of limit, if you're getting the response and this error between intervals, that means, you're sending too many request in a short period of time and another one being daily limit, which resets at midnight, Pacific Time.

Comment: After you enable billing, for the first time, you get $200 or $300 which is valid for a period of 1 year.

Comment: Can you try sending this ? `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=<API_KEY>`

Comment: I try the following url in my layout... but not working.

Comment: Are you getting the same error ? Did you add your API_KEY in the URL ?

Comment: Now the auto complete is not working in my home page and I have the following JS error in my product location page:     **Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at GeoComplete.initGeocoder ...
    at GeoComplete.init .....
    at new GeoComplete ......
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>.....
    at Function.each ....
    at jQuery.fn.init.each....
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.geocomplete ....
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (location:193)
    at mightThrow ...
    at process**

Comment: Can we take this separately in chat ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many tries... 
I confirm that to make the autocomplete work on my homepage and products location
You need to subscribe at least a free account on the google cloud for developpers.
Now that works fine for me

Comment: Hey samy! Im facing the same issue, how did you resolve it with more detail? I can't get it to work :c